# Simply poll & Events Calendar plugins clashing

Tags: plugins, admin

I'm using two plugins that seem to clash:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simply-poll/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/the-events-calendar/

When both activated only the poll plugin shows in the admin menu but when it's deactivated the calendar plugin shows in it's place.

Is there a way to get both plugins working together as they're exactly what I need. I'm running the latest version of WP.

p.s It's more than likely that the problem lies with the poll plugin!

Comment: Time to give out the bounty. You won´t get it back anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *might* be due to the position on the admin sidebar in Simply Poll. Go to simply-poll/lib/admin.php and on line 40 remove the `, 6` from the end of the `add_menu_page()` function and see what happens. I'll have a look at the other plugin as well to check what they are doing.

**Simply Poll developer**

Comment: Just to note, The Events Calendar has the same value for their menu position so it's an argument between the plugins... mine just wins for some reason!